# Return row number(s) for a particular value in a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, numbers, dataframe, row

I have a data frame `(df)` and I was wondering how to return the row number(s) for a particular value `(2585)` in the `4th column (height_chad1)` of the same data frame?

I've tried:

```
row(mydata_2$height_chad1, 2585)
```

and **I get the following error:**

```
Error in factor(.Internal(row(dim(x))), labels = labs) : 
  a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'row'
```

Is there an equivalent line of code that works for data frames instead of matrix-like objects?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `which(mydata_2$height_chad1 == 2585)`

Short example

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3),
                 y = c(5,4,6,7,8,3,2,4))
df
  x y
1 1 5
2 1 4
3 2 6
4 3 7
5 4 8
6 5 3
7 6 2
8 3 4

which(df$x == 3)
[1] 4 8

length(which(df$x == 3))
[1] 2

count(df, vars = "x")
  x freq
1 1    2
2 2    1
3 3    2
4 4    1
5 5    1
6 6    1

df[which(df$x == 3),]
  x y
4 3 7
8 3 4
```

As [Matt Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105773/matt-weller) pointed out, you can use the `length` function.
The `count` function in `plyr` can be used to return the count of each unique column value.

Comment: and if wanted to find the number of times the value 2585 occurred in the same column would I use a similar construct with the function count?                                                                 count(mydata_2$height_chad1 == 2585)

Comment: You could use `length` on the result of the answer provided by Seth or use `sum` instead of `count` in your suggestion. Have you tried the `count` function as you suggest? It's an easy one to test with no danger of breaking anything...!

Comment: Nice solution, but what if you don't just want to look at the x column, what if you want to return the row&col values for each cell in the data frame which equals 3?

Comment: @par Try `df[which(df$x == 3),]`  This returns the [rows,colums].  Leaving one blank indicates all.

Comment: I was searching for how to be selective with columns and yet get the results with row ids of the data.frame. I found an answer to this in my case to get just four columns from @SethB's answer.  df[which(df$x == 3),1:4]

Answer (score 3):

`which(df==my.val, arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: while this could be the right answer it's alway better to add some explanation of what you code does... can you please add some?

Comment: i believe we need at least 2 more votes by other moderators who think a question that simple needs answers with explanations, considering the source code is self-documented; otherwise, the moderator who groundlessly demands such improvements himself desires explaining his actions